# Creating Trigger which affects another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following tables:

employees with [column code_e, name, code_d] and
deps with [code_d, nr_of_employees].

I want to create a trigger on employees after inserting some values that will affect deps.nr_of_employees. 
So, after I insert [1, John, 1], the deps with code_d=1 should have nr_of_employees = nr_of_employees+1;

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: create or alter trigger insert_angajat on employees after insert AS
begin
update deps
set deps.nr_of_employees = deps.nr_of_employees+1 WHERE
deps.cod_d = inserted.cod_d

Comment: you should update your question.

Comment: i've solved it, using UPDATE departament
     SET nr_angajati = nr_angajati + 1
   WHERE cod_d = new.cod_d